# Undefined index error in PHP mysql

Tags: php, mysql, forms

Here is my form code  ,

```
 <form role="form" id="order-form" action="db.php" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Your Full Name">
            </div>
                <div class="form-group">
            <label for="address">Delivery Address</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="address" name="address" placeholder="Address" ></textarea>

                </div>
              <div class="form-group">
             <label for="phone">Phone No</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" name="mobile" placeholder="Phone No">
        </div>
       <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email address</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Quantity</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="quantity" name="quantity">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" >
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Expected Date</label>
        <input id="datepicker" name="date" >
        </div>


      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" >Submit</button>
    </form>
```

THis is my db.php .

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","honey");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$sql="INSERT INTO pre_order
            (name,delivery_location,mobile,email,qty,workdt)
            VALUES
            ('$_POST[name]','$_POST[address]','$_POST[mobile]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[quantity]','$_POST[date]')";
if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
//'echo "Order Received";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

when I click on submit form , It says

**PHP Notices:**

```
Notice: Undefined index: address in C:\xampp\htdocs\office_work\ironbull2\ironbull\db.php on line 12

Notice: Undefined index: date in C:\xampp\htdocs\office_work\ironbull2\ironbull\db.php on line 12
```

The date picker I have used here is a `jquery ui plugin` .

Comment: can you do a print_r($_POST) and see if the form elements are in POST ?

Comment: First check what your $_REQUEST contains, put `echo "<pre>";print_r($_REQUEST);exit;` at the beginning to see if your PHP page receives the date field.
BEFORE RUNNING IN PRODUCTION avoid sql-injections... I suggest you this discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Answer (score 2):

You are not wrapping your array key reference in quotes.

```
$_POST[name]
```

Should be

```
$_POST['name']
```

It is treating them as constants.

Answer (score -1):

It was because you didn't pass the value to the $_POST array.

before submit you need to check those variable have the value or not.

OR

you can add '@' in front of the post. LIKE:

`@$_POST[name]`